# Expo app connection with NodeJS stops working with sockets

Tags: node.js, socket.io, expo

I have an app built with expo and nodejs. Everything is working fine and accordingly. Recently i created an admin panel with ReactJS and trying to create an in app message feature inside my expo app if users want to start a chat with the admin via sockets.

My ReactJS web app works fine, and admin is able to send multiple messages to the user. My problem is with my Expo app.

When the admin sends the user multiple messages to the user, the user receives all the messages and is able to send messages back, but for some reason after a certain number of messages my expo app can no longer connect to my backend and therefore cannot emit any more messages but can still receive messages from the admin which is weird.

Why is this happening?

Expo code

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
const[socket,setSocket]=useState(null)
const message = route.params.message;

useEffect(() => {
    const newsocket =io.connect("http://IP_ADDRESS:9000")
    setMessages(message.Messages)

  newsocket.on('connect', msg => {
        console.log(`user: ${user.id} has joined conversation ${message.id}`,'connection socket id', newsocket.id)
        setSocket(newsocket)
        newsocket.emit('subscribe', message.id);
     });

     newsocket.on("send_message", (msg) => {
      console.log('msg',msg)
         setMessages(messages => [msg.data, ...messages]);
     });
     
     return(()=>{
      console.log(`user: ${user.id} left the room ${message.id} --- socketid ${newsocket.id}`)
      newsocket.disconnect()
      });

  }, []);

const onSend = async(conversationId,senderId,receiverId,message) => {
    const response = await messagesApi.sendMessage({conversationId,senderId,receiverId,message});
    if (!response.ok) return setError(true);
    console.log("sent")
    const to = (user.id===route.params.message.user?route.params.message.admin:route.params.message.user)
    socket.emit('message', { to: to, from: user.id, message,conversationId,data:response.data });
    if(response.ok){
      setText("")
    }
  };
```

NODEJS

```
const express = require("express");
const users = require("./routes/users");
const auth = require("./routes/auth");
const messages = require("./routes/messages");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const compression = require("compression");
const config = require("config");

const app = express();

var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

//Socket.io
const http = require("http");
const socket = require("socket.io");
const server=http.createServer(app);

const io =socket(server,{
  cors: {
    origin:
    ["http://localhost:3000","192.168.1.4:9000"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true
}})

io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
  // connection
  console.log('User '+socket.id+' connected')
  
  // joining a room
  socket.on('subscribe', (room)=> {
    console.log('user socket',socket.id,'joining room', room);
    socket.join(room);
  });

  // send message within room
  socket.on('message', (data) => {
    io.in(data.conversationId).emit('send_message', { 
      message: data.message, receiverId: data.to,senderId:data.from,id:data.conversationId,data:data.data
    });
  })

  // waiting to enter room
  socket.on('waiting', (data)=> {
    console.log('user',socket.id, 'is waiting.');
  });

// disconnect
  socket.on('disconnect',(reason)=>{
    socket.disconnect()    
    console.log('socket disconnected',socket.disconnect().disconnected)
    console.log('USER DISCONNECTED',socket.id)
    if (reason === "io server disconnect") {
      // the disconnection was initiated by the server, you need to reconnect manually
      socket.connect();
      console.log('socket reconnected',socket.id)
    }
  })

})

app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 500000}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(compression());
app.use("/api/users/", users);
app.use("/api/auth/", auth);
app.use("/api/messages", messages);

const port = process.env.PORT || config.get("port");

server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}...`);
});
```

socket.io@3.0.4

socket.io-client@3.0.4

Update

After i send exactly 4 messages the socket.emit in my onSend() stops working i tried to console.log the errors and reconnections, nothing gets printed and also checking my server the sockets does not disconnect.

Comment: Why did you create a new question as a duplicate of [your existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74121600/app-stops-working-when-i-keep-sending-multiple-messages-with-socket-io)? FWIW, the "exactly 4 messages" suggests that `socket.io` using polling, not websockets, and that your browser is refusing to open more connections to your server, so somehow the polling requests are not being returned.

Comment: @robertklep I added transports:['websocket'] and still it is not working in my expo app after now 6 messages the app stops. But my website still works no matter how many messages have been sent.

Comment: You need to check your browser's developer console to see if it can actually set up a websocket connection. I don't think it can.

Comment: @kd12345 Thanks for flagging me from another post. My expertise effectively ends at React and the frontend. Your UI code/logic appears fine to me in that I don't see any overt issues. I'm orders of magnitude less familiar with node/express though, so I can't comment to the correctness of the backend logic. You could test the socket connection by standing up a super simple backend that simply holds the connection and can send/receive test "pings". Perhaps this may reveal any issues in the frontend.